# What are the recommended JVM arguments to run Solr for Java 10?

Tags: java, solr

Most documentation describes settings for Java 8 or earlier e.g. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ShawnHeisey

But many JVM arguments have changed since Java 8.
Here are the arguments we've used previously

```
    # Enable verbose GC logging
GC_LOG_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime \
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp"

# These GC settings have shown to work well for a number of common Solr workloads
GC_TUNE="-XX:NewRatio=3 \
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4 \
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 \
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 \
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-XX:+UseParNewGC \
-XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 \
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark \
-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m \
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly \
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 \
-XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 \
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled \
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled"
```

Arguments like "UseParNewGC" are no longer supported.
The following GC logging flags have also changed https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145092

"CMSScavengeBeforeRemark" also no longer seems supported 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Probably others. What's the new recommendation?

Comment: I guess, all these tools are waiting for jdk 11 which will be next LTS release. Probably that's when they will certify against the updated java version. Support for jdk 10 is ending this september.